# Django save inline formset from template view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Have a master-detail objects with a one-to-many relationship:

```
from django.db import models


class Master(models.Model):

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.IntegerField()


class Detail(models.Model):

    field3 = models.IntegerField()
    field4 = models.IntegerField()
    field5 = models.IntegerField()
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For details, I have a ModelForm and an inline formset:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Master, Detail


class MasterForm(forms.Form):

    field1 = forms.CharField(label='Field 1', max_length=100)
    field2 = forms.IntegerField(label='Field 2')


class DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        exclude = ()


DetailsFormset = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Master, Detail, form=DetailsForm, extra=1)
```

I have a template view:

```
class MasterDetailsView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'app/master_detailsview.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('IN POST!')
        details_formset = DetailsFormset(request.POST)
        if details_formset.is_valid():
            print('FORMSET VALID!')
            Master.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).save()
            details_formset.save()
        else:
            print('ERRORS!')
            print(details_formset.errors)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        master_instance = Master.objects.get(pk=pk)
        context['master_instance'] = master_instance
        if self.request.POST:
            context['details_formset'] = DetailsFormset(self.request.POST, instance=master_instance)
        else:
            context['details_formset'] = DetailsFormset(instance=master_instance)
        return context
```

and the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block contents %}

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Field 1</th>
    <th>Field 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ master_instance.field1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ master_instance.field2 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/ >
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ details_formset.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
<hr/ >

{% endblock %}
```

The error I get in the console:

```
[{'master': ['The inline value did not match the parent instance.']}]
```

I suppose my view is not right. I have tried getting the master record and saving it before the details formset but same error. I am not using CreateView because this is a learning project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `{{details_formset.management_form}}` right under the `csrf_token` in templates